# How to cut string from whois command in Linux

Tags: php, linux, centos, whois

How can I cut a string from the `whois` command with PHP on CentOS Linux?

I just want to cut from `Domain Name:` line to the `>>>Last update...<<<` line.

My code:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('whois facebook.com');
$result = preg_split('/\n\n/', trim($output));
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: write your code, don't post pictures with it!

Comment: Please post the code as text, never an image. Also, tell us what format the data is and what format you want it in after you parse it.

Comment: Sorry guy, Now I'm edit code yet :)

Comment: Your language has libraries to deal with whois queries, so do not shell out for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `sed`:

```
whois facebook.com | sed -n '/^Domain names/,/^>>> Last update/p'
```

This will get all lines between the line starting with `Domain names` and line starting with `>>> Last update`